# Remote desktop connection via intranet only

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, dns, remote-desktop

At home I have two desktop PCs, one which I use for my day to day activities and one which is for storage/server. Since they are in two different rooms I want to be able to connect a remote control session from my daily work computer to the server. However to be absolutely secure I'd like the connection NOT go outside the intranet.

Since, as far as I know, if I were to use something like TeamViewer any connection attempt would first ask their servers or an outside DNS for information I am looking for something that can work on any OS and allow me to connect to the server by directly querying the server machine, at most including the router in the loop, too, without going outside my home network and asking a DNS server or anything.

EDIT:
My daily work PC has Windows 10 Pro, while my server currently has Windows 7 but will be changed to either OpenMediaVault or Manjaro, haven't decided, yet. Which is why I asked for a broad solution, sorry! :D

How can this be achieved?

Comment: What operating system do you have on the source and target machine? Impossible to advise without this information. Please [edit] the question.

Comment: @DavidPostill, your wish is my command! :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to worry unless your NAT router has port forwarding enabled. You can use Windows Firewall to only allow connections from your specific devices. Open Inbound rules in Windows Firewall with advanced settings, open Remote Desktop (TCP-In) and in Scope tab > Local IP and type the IP range (like 192.168.0.1/24). And if you want to allow specific IP addresses from internet then type the individual addresses or range there.

Comment: Thanks, that certainly is helpful! :) Do you know if OpenMediaVault and/or Manjaro have similar settings available? As my server is currently on Windows, but won't be for much longer.

Comment: Sorry, but I am not a Manjaro expert and can't say much, but you can take a look here https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Firewalls and if this answer is OK, then click the big check mark!

Comment: The answer certainly is great, but it's Windows-specific and I was asking for a general OS-agnostic approach, also it doesn't address whether the request will leave my home network, as I am not that concerned with someone connecting from the outside, as I am with someone spoofing/hijacking or otherwise intercepting my request from the outside.

Comment: It will work for any network setup... if you have built-in firewall rules

Comment: Oh, you mean setup the router firewall, or... ?

Comment: Yep that's it, if you don;t have built-in firewall then use your router